# Dynamic Iterating If Statement

Tags: c++, opengl

Im building a snowman in with Opengl and when he gets bigger I want him to get buttons added onto him. So if he gets above x size then 4 buttons and so on. It's very simple to do with if statements, but they are all hardcoded. I am looking for a dynamic way, but I can't seem to come up with anything. Code is below.

```
if(bodyChange >= 2.5){
   renderButton(glm::translate(transform, vec3(0, .5, 0)));
}
if(bodyChange >= 3.5){
   renderButton(glm::translate(transform, vec3(0, 1, 0)));
}
if(bodyChange >= 4.5){
   renderButton(glm::translate(transform, vec3(0, 1.5, 0)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quickly off the top of my head (i hope it works as i have not tested any of it and also assuming I am understanding your question)

```
if (bodyChange >= 2.5) {
    int iterations = ceil(bodyChange - 2.5);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        renderButton(glm::translate(transform, vec3(0, (i + 1) * .5, 0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks a lot. Never thought to use the ceil function, but works great.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that returns the number of buttons you want as a function of size. For instance:

```
int NumButtons(double size)
{
  if (size <= 0)
    return 0;
  }
  int number = (int) (size * 1.5);
  return number;
}
```

I guessed at the constants; adjust them as you like. But this is how I would approach it if I understand your question.